# Can't replacing string with string

Tags: ios, string, swift

I have `UITableViewCell` with `detailTextLabel` which contains string that i want to replace with empty space(in other words to delete).It looks like this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = newsModel.pubDate
```

Now, the problem is that when i write `cell.detailTextLabel?.text?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+0000", withString: " ")`

its not working and compiler says:

> "Result of call 
>   'stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(_:withString:options:range:)' is
>   unused"

Anyone can tell me the solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString:withString:` method *returns* a string that is the *result* of replacing your search string with the replacement. The warning means that you are calling a method with a non-void return value that you aren't using.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:) (italics added by me for emphasis)

> Returns a *new* string in which all occurrences of a target string in the receiver are replaced by another given string.

You can use this:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = newsModel.pubDate.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+0000", withString: " ")
```

The reason you get this warning is because the method doesn't modify the original string and *returns* a *new* string, which you don't use. If you were to use

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.text? = cell.detailTextLabel?.text?.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("+0000", withString: " ")
```

You wouldn't get the warning because you are assigning the return value to the cell text and therefore "using" the result of the call.

The two methods are exactly the same, except one is shorter.

Comment: Worked! Thank you very much !

Comment: @CDDsw please accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a time limit. OP will have to wait around 3 more minutes IIRC.